# React router is showing No Router matched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]App.js

```
import Login from './Auth/components/login/Login';
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './Auth/components/signin/Signin';
import Home from './Home/Home';
import Dogs from './pets/Dogs';
import Cats from './pets/Cats';
import Others from './pets/Others';
import Pets from './pets/Pets';
import { Header } from './ui/Header/Header';
import { ContextClickValue } from './context/ContextClick';
import Cart from './Auth/components/cart/Cart';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} >
          </Route>
        </Routes>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />}></Route>
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />}></Route>
          <Route path="pets" element={< Outlet />}>
            <Route index element={<Pets />} />
            <Route path="dogs" element={<Dogs />} />
            <Route path="cats" element={<Cats />} />
            <Route path="others" element={<Others />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import { menuItems } from "../../Home/MenuItems";
import MenuItemComponent from "./MenuItemComponent";
import HeaderStyles from "./Header.module.css";
import { ContextClick, ContextClickValue } from "../../context/ContextClick";
import AddShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddShoppingCart';
import  {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


export function Header() {
    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart.cart)
    const  navigate = useNavigate()

    function navigateToCart(e){
         e.preventDefault()
        navigate('/cart')
    }
    let  total = 0;
    return (
        <section className={HeaderStyles.navbar}>
            <header>
                <h4 className={HeaderStyles.logo}>PETSHOP</h4>
                <nav>
                        <MenuItemComponent items={menuItems} />
                </nav>
            </header>
            <section style={{ float:'right',margin:30, color:'white'}}>
            <AddShoppingCartIcon  style={{cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={navigateToCart}/>
            {cart.forEach(item => {
                total += item.quantity
            })}
            <span>{total}</span>
            </section>
        </section>
    )
}
```

i have tried using Navlink also

```
 <NavLink to="/cart">
             <AddShoppingCartIcon  style={{cursor:'pointer'}} />
            {cart.forEach(item => {
                total += item.quantity
            })}
            </NavLink>
```

1. I am trying to to navigate to cart (i don't know why it is not working)
2. In dev Tools it is showing to matching Router (i tried clearing cache and hard reload and restarted my server)
3. I have replaced cart to login for checking it is Navigation Successfully
4. sandBox link
   https://codesandbox.io/p/github/muthyalaDivyaVenkatesh/authentication/master

Can Anyone let me know Why it is Not Working .

Comment: I don't see any reason for the `"/cart"` route to not be reachable, can you navigate to `"/cart"` manually via the address bar? Is the issue with no route match specific to the `"/"` route?

Comment: i have added screenshot can you check @DrewReese

Comment: I see. Thanks, I was wondering why the `Home` component was on it's own route in its own `Routes` component. Can you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the routing issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: sure i will do it and let u know Thanks:)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/muthyalaDivyaVenkatesh/authentication/master  

@DrewReese i have pushed my code to sandbox can u help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

You are rendering 2 `Header` components, one inside the `Home` component within a `Routes` component, and another outside the routes on it's own. The `Header` renders links, one of which targets `"/cart"`, but the `Routes` component isn't rendering a route for that path. The *other* `Routes` component is missing a route rendering on path `"/"`.

Additionally, the `Cart` component isn't returning mapped JSX for the cart data selected from state.

```
function Cart() {  
  const cart = useSelector((state)=> state.cart.cart)
    
  return (
    <div>
      {cart.map(cartItem => {
        <ShoppingCard                  // <-- not returned!!
          imageUrl={cartItem.imageUrl}
          price={cartItem.price}
        />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

## Solution

Create a layout component that renders the `Header` component, and remove the `Header` from the `Home` component.

App.js

```
const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
            <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
            <Route path="pets">
              <Route index element={<Pets />} />
              <Route path="dogs" element={<Dogs />} />
              <Route path="cats" element={<Cats />} />
              <Route path="others" element={<Others />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <ImageChanging />
      <TopDeals />
    </>
  );
}
```

Cart.js

```
function Cart() {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cart);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cart</h1>
      {cart.map((cartItem) => {
        return (          // <-- return the ShoppingCard component
          <ShoppingCard
            width={300}
            height={300}
            {...cartItem}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```